# Convert string to long in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

How can I convert string to long in excel macro. CLng is giving me type mismatch error

```
Dim wStr As String
Dim w As Long

wStr = "=RAND() * 0.3 + 0.35"
w = CLng(wStr)
```

Comment: The mismatch is due to the fact that "=RAND() * 0.3 + 0.35" cannot be interpreted as a long. CLng will work on a string that is already a number, like "0.35". You need first to evaluate the expression "=RAND()..." to a number, like RonnieDickinson suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of your error is that `CDbl` expects a numeric value or a string that *looks* like a number.  the string `"=RAND() * 0.3 + 0.35"` itself does not look like a number, even though it will *evaluate* to a number.

What are you actually trying to achieve here?

If its to get a long integer result from the formula =RAND() * 0.3 + 0.35, use

```
Dim w as Long
w = Rnd() * 0.3 + 0.35
```

If its to emulate a cell formula use

```
Dim w as Long
w = Application.Evaluate("=RAND() * 0.3 + 0.35")
```

As to the formula itself, why this construct?  It will return Single in the range [0.35, 0.65) which when rounded to a Long will return 0 or 1 at 50% probability of each.
Why not use

```
w = Rnd()
```

or

```
w = Application.Evaluate("=RAND()")
```

or

```
w = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 1)
```

or is there some other reason I've missed?

Answer (score 4):

Try the formula for w below.

```
w = CLng(Evaluate(wStr))
```

Or forget trying to use an "Excel formula", and go straight to VBA with with its random function counterpart

```
w = CLng(Rnd() * 0.3 + 0.35)
```